# Fastest way to output very large data to stdout in Java

Tags: java

I want to print a lot of data to Stdout in the fastest possible way. One way is that I use a StringBuilder and keep appending the output to it and then print the stringbuffer. But sometimes this fails when the data to be printed is more than the maximum allowable size and gives Memory Limited Exceeded error. (for example in online judges). Is there some other better and faster way to print data?

Comment: write it to a file instead. "stdout" and "lots of data" don't live in the same worlds.

Comment: Print the buffer, when you've reached a specified amount and clear the buffer.

Comment: there is no *fast* way to print to `stdout` it is the slowest possible way to output data, because it completely depends on the device that is receiving the output, writing to a file directly will be much more efficient

Comment: @JarrodRoberson funny story: on a project I was working on about 11 years ago, we noticed that a program was running much slower than expected on one of our fastest machines, a dual-CPU Xeon workstation. Eventually we discovered that we could make it run 10x faster by minimizing the console window. Our performance bottleneck was the Intel GMA graphics decelerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
try {    
  BufferedWriter log = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
  //.....
  log.flush();
}
```

Although writing to a file directly will be more efficient